# Are SRFI/41 and Racket/stream different?

Tags: stream, racket

`in-range` in Racket returns a stream. There are plenty of functions defined on streams from `racket/stream` library. However i can't use a function `stream-take` from `srfi/41` on them. I wanted to execute

```
(stream-take 5 (in-range 10))
```

It complained that `stream-take: non-stream argument`.

```
(stream->list (stream-cons 10 (in-range 10)))
```

The above throws the following error:

```
stream-promise: contract violation;
 given value instantiates a different structure type with the same name
  expected: stream?
  given: #<stream>
```

However:

```
(stream->list (stream-cons 10 stream-null)) ;; works
(stream->list (stream-cons 10 empty-stream)) ;; works
```

both work fine.

Does the above mean that streams from `racket/stream` and `srfi/41` are incompatible? How can i take 10 items from a `racket/stream` stream without reinventing the wheel?

Racket 5.3.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the kind of stream that `(in-range 10)` produces is different from `srfi/41` streams. In general, you can't expect `srfi/41` functions to work on all streams in Racket because a Racket "stream" is actually a generic datatype that dispatches to different method implementations (see [`gen:stream`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html?q=gen%3Astream#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstream..rkt%29._gen~3astream%29%29)). In contrast, `srfi/41` expects only its own datatype.

(`stream-take` should probably be added to `racket/stream` though)

If you want to take 10 items from `racket/stream`, use `(for/list ([x some-stream] [e 10]) x)`.